# In typescript, how can I safely render an anchor tag in a string as a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my react application, I am getting data from a database and displaying it on the webpage. One of the data, `docs.description` is a string like this `"Click this link <a href='www.example.com'>Example</a>"`.

Currently everything I have tried is just printing out the entire string or just not working. I want to display the text on the site with the links interpreted and displayed as links should be, like: Click this link [Example](https://www.example.com)

Here is the section of code if it helps

```
export const DocContainer: FC<{docs: AssetDocs}> = ({docs}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.docContainer}>
      <Text h2 style={{color:"#26ff91"}}>Docs</Text>
      {docs && docs.description}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Consider using React's own aptly-named `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: @ConnorMooneyhan this sounds dangerous :P is it bad practice?

Comment: Well, you can decide for yourself whether it's dangerous for your use case, but the reason it might be is that it allows an easy entryway for Cross Site Scripting attacks. You can read more about them here and see if it might be relevant to your situation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: @ConnorMooneyhan thanks, used that and it did the trick! Just curious, why post answer as comment instead of regular answer?

Comment: I guess I just don't feel comfortable enough with it to actually suggest it in an answer.

Comment: @ConnorMooneyhan got it thanks! it's a POC so it'll do for now. I;ll leave it to the UI guys to fix it up lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually 2 way to do this

The first is the `useRef` hook which will give you a reference of an HTML element (in your case it would be the parent `div`) which you can use as if you were in plain JS.

**TL;DR**  you can access the `innerHTML` prop

```
const ref = useRef();

return <div ref={ref}>
    // stuff goes here
</div>
```

Or you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` React prop

```
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "YOUR_HTML_STRING" }}></div>
```

This should be sanitized tho before you actually use it, because you can get any kind of injection attack.

Personally I haven't used it, but I found [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html-react) which would do the job and it's moderately popular.

Comment: Awesome, does useRef need to be sanitized as well?

Comment: No, that's safely injected HTML. Check out the `useRef` [docs](https://hu.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) for more info.

Comment: Merely writing `const ref = useRef();` and `ref={ref}` is perfectly safe, but if you go on to use the ref to set inner html then yes, you need to sanitize that.

Comment: Yeah.. my bad. I had to look it up

Answer (score 0):

Combining all the valuable input from everyone, I was able to create what I believe to be a safe solution using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` combined with `sanitizeHtml`

```
import { Text } from "@zeit-ui/react";
import React, { FC } from "react";
import styles from "./styles.module.css"
import { AssetDocs } from "./types";
import sanitizeHtml from "sanitize-html"


export const DocContainer: FC<{docs: AssetDocs}> = ({docs}) => {

  const createMarkup = () => {
    if (docs.description)
      return {__html: sanitizeHtml(docs.description)};
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.docContainer}>
      <Text h2 style={{color:"#26ff91"}}>Docs</Text>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks everyone!